# How to apply table to categorical columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with both numeric and categorical columns and I want to apply `table` function to all categorical columns (print out count of level occurances per column). Is there an elegant solution to this, perhaps with `lapply`?

Comment: Make a reproducible example with some sample data we can cut and paste. If you have a solution that you don't think is truly optimal supply that too.

Answer (score 0):

Get the *factor* class

`data.class <- sapply(df, class)
col <- data.class[data.class=="factor"]`

Apply *table*

`with(df, sapply(df[,which(names(df) %in% names(col))], table))`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution:

```
#Filter out categorical columns
cat_DF <- DF[, sapply(DF, is.categorical)]

#Apply table to the filtered columns
lapply(cat_DF, function(x) table(x, useNA="ifany"))
```

The output is a named list with the respective categorical distributions.